# Looking to log memory usage and cpu usage every x interval on a box

Tags: scripts, memory-usage

I am looking to monitor memory and cpu usage on the box every minute or so. Any recommended ways on doing this?

Comment: Are you looking for monitoring/reporting/trending/graphing or more like "WTF happened at 3PM"? For the latter case: I would suggest [`atop` as explained in my answer on SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com/a/514587/157409).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nagios for monitoring/alerting and graphite for trending are my favourites for this.